# javax.ejb.EJBException a la hora de crear

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, jpa

Tengo un proyecto al cual unos módulos les sirve el CRUD y los deja Crear pero a otros no; a la hora de crear que es cuando llamo el metodo save() arroja un error `javax.ejb.EJBException`.
No sé qué está mal ya que en otros módulos sirve perfectamente el CRUD y en este no. Cabe resaltar que esta tabla "PRODUCTO" también la usa otro módulo (portafolio) para crear productos en el cual tampoco funciona el método `save()` que es para crear, pero al resto de métodos si les sirve: solo tengo problema con el `save()`. Cuando creo los productos en la BD sí me los trae a  la vista, pero de la vista a la BD no sirve.

En el navegador aparece: *Error javax.ejb.EJBException*; en el servidor me aparece esto:

> usuario_inventarios_productos.xhtml:1 POST localhost:8080/ocem3/faces/usuario_inventarios_productos.xhtml 500 (Internal Server Error)

Y en el servidor aparece:

> FATAL: JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.faces.FacesException durante el procesamiento de INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Mensaje=#{productoController.save()}: javax.ejb.EJBException FATAL: #{productoController.save()}: javax.ejb.EJBException javax.faces.FacesException: #{productoController.save()}: javax.ejb.EJBException

Este es el html:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    
             xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
        <h:head>
            <title>Inventarios</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"></meta>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css"></link>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <!-- SideBar -->
        <section class="full-box cover dashboard-sideBar">
        
        <div class="full-box dashboard-sideBar-bg btn-menu-dashboard"></div>
        <div class="full-box dashboard-sideBar-ct">
                    <!--SideBar Title -->
        <ul class="full-box list-unstyled text-center">
        <div class="full-box text-uppercase text-center text-titles dashboard-sideBar-title">
                <i class="zmdi zmdi-close btn-menu-dashboard visible-xs"></i>
        </div>
        </ul>
                    <!-- SideBar User info -->
        <div class="full-box dashboard-sideBar-UserInfo">
            <figure class="full-box">
                <img src="./assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="UserIcon"></img>
            </figure>
            <ul class="full-box list-unstyled text-center">
                <div class="full-box text-uppercase text-center text-titles dashboard-sideBar-title">
                    Sistema empresarial <i class="zmdi zmdi-close btn-menu-dashboard visible-xs"></i>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
                    <!-- SideBar Menu -->
        <ul class="list-unstyled full-box dashboard-sideBar-Menu">
            <li>
                <a href="inicio.xhtml"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-reorder zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Inicio</a>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="#!" class="btn-sideBar-SubMenu">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-account zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Usuarios<i class="zmdi zmdi-caret-down pull-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled full-box">
                    <li>
                        <a href="admin.xhtml"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account-add zmdi-hc-fw"></i>Crear usuario</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="#!" class="btn-sideBar-SubMenu">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-card zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Inventarios<i class="zmdi zmdi-caret-down pull-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled full-box">
                    <li>
                        <a href="usuario_inventarios_productos.xhtml"><i class="zmdi zmdi-card zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Productos terminados</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="insumos.xhtml"><i class="zmdi zmdi-view-stream zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Insumos</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="#!" class="btn-sideBar-SubMenu">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar-check zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Producción<i class="zmdi zmdi-caret-down pull-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled full-box">
                    <li>
                        <a href="usuario_produccion.xhtml"><i class="zmdi zmdi-truck zmdi-hc-fw"></i>Orden de producción</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="#!" class="btn-sideBar-SubMenu">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-accounts zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Proveedores<i class="zmdi zmdi-caret-down pull-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled full-box">
                    <li>
                        <a href="proveedores.xhtml"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account-add  zmdi-hc-fw">Terceros</i> </a>
                    </li>             
                    <li>
                        <a href="compras.xhtml"><i class=" zmdi zmdi-shopping-cart zmdi-hc-fw">Orden de compra</i> </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="#!" class="btn-sideBar-SubMenu">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-folder zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Portafolio<i class="zmdi zmdi-caret-down pull-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled full-box">
                    <li>
                        <a href="portafolio.xhtml"><i class="zmdi zmdi-camera-add zmdi-hc-fw"></i>Productos</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            
            <li>
                <a href="#!" class="btn-sideBar-SubMenu">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-wrench zmdi zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Configuraciónes avanzadas <i class="zmdi zmdi-caret-down pull-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled full-box">
                    <li>
                        <a href="configuracion.xhtml"><i class="zmdi zmdi-settings zmdi zmdi-hc-fw"></i>configuracion</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>       
        </div>
        </section>
    
            <!-- Content page-->
            <section class="full-box dashboard-contentPage">
                <!-- NavBar -->
                <nav class="full-box dashboard-Navbar">
                    <ul class="full-box list-unstyled text-right">
                        <li class="pull-left">
                            <a href="#!" class="btn-menu-dashboard"><i class="zmdi zmdi-more-vert"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#!" class="btn-Notifications-area">
                                <i class="zmdi zmdi-notifications-none"></i>
                    
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#!" class="btn-search">
                                <i class="zmdi zmdi-search"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#!" class="btn-exit-system">
                                <i class="zmdi zmdi-power"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <!-- Content page -->
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1 class="text-titles"><i class="zmdi  zmdi-hc-fw"></i> Productos / <small>Stock</small></h1>
                    </div>
                    
                      <div class="container-fluid"  style="margin: 20px 0;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                          <h:graphicImage url="assets/img/caja.png" alt="calendar" class="img-responsive center-box" style="max-width: 160px;"></h:graphicImage>
                    </div>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#new" data-toggle="tab">Agregar un nuevo producto</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#list" data-toggle="tab">Ver inventario</a></li>
                                </ul>
                           <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="new">
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
                                                <h:form>
                                                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                                <label>Código de Producto</label>
                                                                <h:inputText value="#{productoController.producto.codigoProducto}" converter="#{Integer}" class="form-control"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                                <label>Nombre de Producto</label>
                                                                <h:inputText value="#{productoController.producto.nombreProducto}" converter="#{Integer}" class="form-control"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                                <label>Stock</label>
                                                                <h:inputText value="#{productoController.producto.stockProducto}" class="form-control"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                                <label>Valor de Producto</label>
                                                                <h:inputText value="#{productoController.producto.valorProducto}" class="form-control"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                           
                                                            
                                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                               <label>Seleccioanr categoría</label>  
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                                <h:selectOneMenu  class="form-select"  value="#{productoController.categoriaSelect}" converter="#{Integer}">
                                                                    <f:selectItems var="r" itemLabel="#{r.nombreCategoria}" itemValue="#{r.idCategoria}" value="#{productoController.getAllCategoria()}"></f:selectItems>
                                                                </h:selectOneMenu> 
                                                            </div>
                                                               
                                                            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                                <p class="text-center">
                                                                    <h:commandButton action="#{productoController.save()}" class="btn btn-info btn-raised btn-sm  zmdi-floppy" value="Guardar"></h:commandButton>
                                                                    <h:commandButton action="#{productoController.clear()}" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised btn-sm  zmdi-floppy"  value="Limpiar"></h:commandButton>
                                                             </p>
                                                                
                                          
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
    
                                                </h:form>
    
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  
    
                                </div>
                           
    
             
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <h:dataTable  class="table table-striped table-hover" value="#{productoController.findAll()}"   var="producto">
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">Código de Producto</f:facet>
                                                <p>#{producto.codigoProducto}</p>
                                            </h:column>
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">Nombre de Producto</f:facet>
                                                <p>#{producto.nombreProducto}</p>
                                            </h:column>
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">Stock</f:facet>
                                                <p>#{producto.stockProducto}</p>
                                            </h:column>
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">Valor de Producto</f:facet>
                                                <p>#{producto.valorProducto}</p>
                                            </h:column>
                                           
                                            
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">Categoría</f:facet>
                                                <p>#{producto.categoriaidCategoria.nombreCategoria}</p>
                                            </h:column>
    
    
                                            <h:column>
                                                <f:facet name="header">Opciones</f:facet>
                                                <h:form>
                                                    <h:commandButton action="#{productoController.delete(producto)}" value="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger btn-raised btn-xs"></h:commandButton>
                                                    <h:commandButton action="#{productoController.update(producto)}" value="Actualizar" class="btn btn-success btn-raised btn-xs"></h:commandButton>
                                                </h:form>
                                            </h:column>
                                        </h:dataTable>    
    
    
                                        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
                                            <li class="disabled"><a href="#!">«</a></li>
                                            <li class="active"><a href="#!">1</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#!">2</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#!">3</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#!">4</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#!">5</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#!">»</a></li>
                                        </ul>
    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div> 
                </div>
                         </div>
            </section>
    
    
    
    
            <!-- Notifications area -->
            <section class="full-box Notifications-area">
                <div class="full-box Notifications-bg btn-Notifications-area"></div>
                <div class="full-box Notifications-body">
                    <div class="Notifications-body-title text-titles text-center">
                        Notificaciones <i class="zmdi zmdi-close btn-Notifications-area"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
    
    
            <!--====== Scripts -->
            <script src="./js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./js/material.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./js/ripples.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
             <c:if test="#{messagesController.titulo != null}">
                <script>
                    swal.fire("#{messagesController.titulo}", "#{messagesController.descripcion}", "#{messagesController.icono}");
                </script>
            </c:if>
            <script>
                $.material.init();
            </script>
            
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

Este es el controller en donde tengo los métodos:

```
package com.mycompany.ocem2.controller;
    import com.mycompany.ocem2.entitys.Producto;
    import com.mycompany.ocem2.services.CategoriaFacade;
    import com.mycompany.ocem2.entitys.Categoria;
    import com.mycompany.ocem2.services.ProductoFacade;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.ejb.EJB;
    import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import javax.inject.Named;
    
    
    /**
     *
     * @author SoporteTI
     */
    @Named(value = "productoController")
    @RequestScoped
    public class productoController{
    
        @EJB
        private ProductoFacade productoFacade;
        private Producto producto = new Producto();
        @EJB
        private CategoriaFacade categoriaFacade;
        private Integer categoriaSelect;
        
        
        @Inject
        private MessagesController messagesController;
        /**
         * Creates a new instance of productoController
         */
        public productoController() {
        }
    
        public List<Producto> findAll(){
            return productoFacade.findAll();
        }
        
        public void update(Producto producto) {
            this.producto = producto;
            this.categoriaSelect = producto.getCategoriaidCategoria().getIdCategoria();
        }
    
        public void clear() {
            producto = new Producto();
        }
    
        public void delete(Producto producto) {
            productoFacade.remove(producto);
            messagesController.setTitulo("El usuario ha sido eliminado exitosamente!");
        }
        
         public void save() {
            
            productoFacade.create(producto);      
                
        }
         
        public List<Categoria> getAllCategoria(){
            return categoriaFacade.findAll(); 
        }
       
        public Producto getProducto() {
            return producto;
        }
    
        public void setProducto(Producto producto) {
            this.producto = producto;
        }
        
        public Integer getCategoriaSelect() {
            return categoriaSelect;
        }
    
        public void setCategoriaSelect(Integer categoriaSelect) {
            this.categoriaSelect = categoriaSelect;
        }
    
    }
```

Esta es la entidad:

```
package com.mycompany.ocem2.entitys;
    
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.persistence.Basic;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.Lob;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Temporal;
    import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author SoporteTI
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "producto")
    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Producto.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Producto p")})
    public class Producto implements Serializable {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "idProducto")
        private int idProducto;
        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
        @Column(name = "codigoProducto")
        private String codigoProducto;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
        @Column(name = "nombreProducto")
        private String nombreProducto;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
        @Column(name = "stockProducto")
        private String stockProducto;
        // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "valorProducto")
        private BigDecimal valorProducto;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Lob
        @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
        @Column(name = "fotoProducto")
        private String fotoProducto;
        @Column(name = "created_at")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date createdAt;
        @Column(name = "updated_at")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date updatedAt;
        @JoinColumn(name = "categoria_idCategoria", referencedColumnName = "idCategoria")
        @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        private Categoria categoriaidCategoria;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productocodigoProducto")
        private List<Produccion> produccionList;
    
        public Producto() {
        }
    
        public Producto(String codigoProducto) {
            this.codigoProducto = codigoProducto;
        }
    
        public Producto(String codigoProducto, int idProducto, String nombreProducto, String stockProducto, BigDecimal valorProducto, String fotoProducto) {
            this.codigoProducto = codigoProducto;
            this.idProducto = idProducto;
            this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
            this.stockProducto = stockProducto;
            this.valorProducto = valorProducto;
            this.fotoProducto = fotoProducto;
        }
    
        public int getIdProducto() {
            return idProducto;
        }
    
        public void setIdProducto(int idProducto) {
            this.idProducto = idProducto;
        }
    
        public String getCodigoProducto() {
            return codigoProducto;
        }
    
        public void setCodigoProducto(String codigoProducto) {
            this.codigoProducto = codigoProducto;
        }
    
        public String getNombreProducto() {
            return nombreProducto;
        }
    
        public void setNombreProducto(String nombreProducto) {
            this.nombreProducto = nombreProducto;
        }
    
        public String getStockProducto() {
            return stockProducto;
        }
    
        public void setStockProducto(String stockProducto) {
            this.stockProducto = stockProducto;
        }
    
        public BigDecimal getValorProducto() {
            return valorProducto;
        }
    
        public void setValorProducto(BigDecimal valorProducto) {
            this.valorProducto = valorProducto;
        }
    
        public String getFotoProducto() {
            return fotoProducto;
        }
    
        public void setFotoProducto(String fotoProducto) {
            this.fotoProducto = fotoProducto;
        }
    
        public Date getCreatedAt() {
            return createdAt;
        }
    
        public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
            this.createdAt = createdAt;
        }
    
        public Date getUpdatedAt() {
            return updatedAt;
        }
    
        public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
            this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
        }
    
        public Categoria getCategoriaidCategoria() {
            return categoriaidCategoria;
        }
    
        public void setCategoriaidCategoria(Categoria categoriaidCategoria) {
            this.categoriaidCategoria = categoriaidCategoria;
        }
    
        @XmlTransient
        public List<Produccion> getProduccionList() {
            return produccionList;
        }
    
        public void setProduccionList(List<Produccion> produccionList) {
            this.produccionList = produccionList;
        }
    
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 0;
            hash += (codigoProducto != null ? codigoProducto.hashCode() : 0);
            return hash;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object object) {
            // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
            if (!(object instanceof Producto)) {
                return false;
            }
            Producto other = (Producto) object;
            if ((this.codigoProducto == null && other.codigoProducto != null) || (this.codigoProducto != null && !this.codigoProducto.equals(other.codigoProducto))) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "com.mycompany.ocem2.entitys.Producto[ codigoProducto=" + codigoProducto + " ]";
        }
    
        public void setIdProducto(Producto producto) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
        }
        
    }
```

y este es el service Facade:

```
package com.mycompany.ocem2.services;
    
    import com.mycompany.ocem2.entitys.Producto;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author SoporteTI
     */
    @Stateless
    public class ProductoFacade extends AbstractFacade<Producto> {
    
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ocempresarial")
        private EntityManager em;
    
        @Override
        protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            return em;
        }
    
        public ProductoFacade() {
            super(Producto.class);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Se tan amable de publicar el error así podemos determinar el punto de origen y la naturaleza del error.

Comment: Hola, si, ya la edite al momento de responder el comentario. muchas gracias.